# tsql -group by by max datetime in rows

Tags: t-sql

I have a table and it's data looks like this:

```
 id         name       date
 ---------  ---------  ----------
 1          a          2012-08-30 10:36:27.393
 1          b          2012-08-30 14:36:27.393
 2          c          2012-08-30 13:36:27.393
 2          d          2012-08-30 16:36:27.393
```

I retrieve the max datetime with this query:

```
SELECT id,Max(date) as mymaxdate
FROM table1
group by id
```

This query givse me two rows like this:

```
1     2012-08-30 14:36:27.393
2     2012-08-30 16:36:27.393
```

It's correct, but how can i change it to retrieve this result?

```
1   b  2012-08-30 14:36:27.393
2   d  2012-08-30 16:36:27.393
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+

```
WITH cteMaxDate AS (
    SELECT id, name, date, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM table1
)
SELECT id, name, date
    FROM cteMaxDate
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: thanks it works good can you show me how to change it to entity query?

Comment: @motevallizadeh: I can't. I'm not even sure things like the use of a CTE would translate. Perhaps you can open a new question for the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options:

```
select 
    t1.id
    ,t1.name
    ,t1.date 
from 
    table1 t1
    inner join (
        SELECT id,Max(date) as mymaxdate
        FROM table1
        group by id
    ) mt1
        on t1.id = mt1.id
        and t1.date = mt1.mymaxdate
```

Comment: This will return extra rows if there are ties for max date within id groups.  Since the original attempt involved a GROUP BY I assume the poster only wants one row in that case.

Comment: thanks it works good can you show me how to change it to entity query?

Comment: @GilM that's true - but then you need to define the criteria which row name to pick when there are two with the same date, if that is not relevant than the Joe's answer would be best. Otherwise you may wrap the results in another group by with max(name) or min(name) depending on the criteria.

Comment: I think Joe's answer is best.  If there's a preference for which row to pick based on other columns, it can be implemented using the ORDER BY in the ROW NUMBER function.